# Google site map

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap, google-search

i have been whondering this for a long time now, how does this work? Their whole site is indexed and all pages are visible in this way. Can you please point me in the right direction?

I could not find any pointers in the Google Search Console.

What i would like to achieve is found in the image link below

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaOSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Google does it automatically. And they keep in secret how and what they are looking for to create it. [Here is what Google says about "sitelinks"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334)

Good way to get what you want is to implement good link hierarchy in your site. [Here is an article that digs deep into how to get sitelinks in google search results](https://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/sitelinks.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Google shows this kind of results only when:

1. The website is ranked in good position (May be at top #1) for the given search query.
2. Google doesn't find the next super quality website to show in the second position. So it take the next popular page in the same website. And also listing the similar pages based on the popularity.

You can beat this listing, what you need to do is brand marketing.

Answer (score 0):

The photo you've provided highlights "Google Sitelinks," a form of indented results that appear for searches where a particular domain is by far the leading result for the search you've conducted.

The most common situations where you will encounter these Sitelinks is when searching for branded terms.

Back in 2008 when this feature was released, it was with simple text links only and didn't include the descriptive copy underneath each of the indented, blue links. I covered this extensively in a [blog post I wrote](http://www.ericlander.com/google-sitelinks-research-examples-theories-and-best-practices-project-big-water/) at the time.

Extracting from that a bit and adjusting some language given the 7 years since, here's how I would describe the functionality:

1. The first and most annoying is the fact about the Sitelinks program
   is that it is an entirely automated system.  You can’t click a
   button or change a setting to enable Sitelinks.
2. If you want to have any influence at all on your Sitelinks, you’ll
   want to get your site verified and included into your Google
   Search Console account.
3. When Sitelinks do appear, they tend to be shown most frequently
   based on your site's top landing pages. Leverage your analytics here
   if possible to better understand what those pages may be.
4. Once Sitelinks begin to appear, you may not like one or more of the
   results. In this case, you should leverage the "Demote a Sitelink"
   option. This (and all controls of the Sitelinks program) are
   available within Google Search Console by navigating to "Search
   Appearance" and then "Sitelinks."

I hope this helps!